# Oпять, еще раз and снова

Tags: выбор-слова

For non-Russian-speakers it might be not so easy to detect the difference between words that are *almost* synonyms; for instance the difference between "теперь" и "сейчас" (cf. [this question](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/1062/what-is-the-difference-between-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8C-and-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81)).

When would you use "**опять**", when "**еще раз**" and when "**снова**"? (assuming, of course, that I'm not wrong and they are indeed (*almost*) synonyms)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer by Netch is wrong.

"Еще раз" "one more time" is used when you expect that the event happens or will happen for the last time, you do not expect it to repeat again.

"Опять" and "снова" are used for actions that you expect to repeat again and again.

"Опять" is usually used for undesirable events.

> Опять придется его об этом просить.

I do not want to irritate him with my request again but I have no other choice.

> Ничего страшного, я снова его об этом попрошу.

Nothing bad, I can ask him again and he will do it without negative reaction.

> Я попрошу его об этом еще раз.

I will ask him again one more time (I hope it will be the last time).

Also "снова" may refer to starting anew a prolonged action, while "опять" may mean a continuation of the previous action.

> Он снова начал готовиться к экзаменам

Possibly a year passed from the last time and he chose another university so he started to prepare anew.

> Он опять начал готовиться к экзаменам

Probably something interrupted his preparations for a day or two and now he continued the preparations.

> Он решил построить дом снова

He decided to build a house anew in place of his previous house that was destroyed.

> Он опять решил построить дом

He again decided to build a house (he already decided so previously but changed his mind).

In short, "опять" is used when you want to underline the unavoidable repetitiveness of the event:

"опять начались дожди", "опять я заболел", "опять крысы испортили продукты", "он опять стал принимать наркотики"

"Снова" is used when you want to underline that the event starts anew and the results of the previous event are lost or that the event gained new momentum:

"придется снова собирать все документы", "он снова влюбился и снова приобрел интерес к жизни", "после выхода из тюрьмы он снова начал строить свою карьеру".

Comment: So `oпять` only applies for undesirable things, right? It would be then absurd to say e.g. `она опять получила Нобелевскую премию`?

Comment: @c.p. usually to undesirable. The phrase "она опять получила Нобелевскую премию" would mean either that you dislike the fact that she got a noble prize again (you think she does not deserve) or that this event does not surprise you: you expected it, it is little surprising to you. Like in "она - любовница председателя Нобелевского комитета, не удивительно, что она опять получила Нобелевскую премию". Or "не смотря на то, что есть много других талантливых кандидатов, премию опять дали ей".

Comment: On the contrary "она снова получила нобелевскую премию" would imply that this new prize is not related to the previous one and she did much new work to get it. She started a new research and got a new prize.

Comment: @Anixx do you have any references to dictionaties? If no, all your comments that I'm wrong are your personal evidence against my personal evidence, and shall be treated only as dialectal/environmental differences. I have no objections against your personal evidence, but when you say I'm plainly wrong, you should prove this.

Comment: @Netch in tha National corpus of the Russian language you can see that the word "опять" is used with future tense (in sequences "надо опять, опять надо, опять будет") more often than "снова".

Comment: http://search-beta.ruscorpora.ru/ngram.xml?mode=main&t1=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%C2%A0%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C&t2=%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%C2%A0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE&t3=%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%C2%A0%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82&start=1970&end=2013&smoothing=3 http://search-beta.ruscorpora.ru/ngram.xml?mode=main&t1=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%C2%A0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0&t2=%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%C2%A0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE&t3=%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%C2%A0%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82&start=1970&end=2013&smoothing=3

Comment: @Anixx this comparison is weird because you don't have alternatives on a same field. Better is to compare e.g. "будет {опять/снова/ещё раз}" or "{опять/снова/ещё раз} придёт", with 3 alternatives on the same chart, and these results show that "опять" for future tends to cease (despite was popular 30-40 years ago), while "снова" tends to grow. The most extreme case to grow is "будет снова".

Comment: @Netch the growth for this sequence is only for the last 3 years. It is not indicative of anything. Anyway, your claim that "опять" is not used for the future is a plain nonsence, evident to any native speaker.

Comment: @Anixx please be accurate in nuances. "Опять" is hardly used for planned actions in future. It can be used for conditional future ("Если он опять придёт, прогони его"), but this isn't future in English (it's future-in-the-past or simply conditional, depending on style). And, rephrasing you, "опять" for planned actions is a plain nonsence, evident to any native speaker:)

Comment: @Netch you cannot be a native speaker if you claim so. "Опять" is very widely used in future declarative mood. Sometimes it cannot be substituted with "снова" without loss of meaning, such as in "опять будут воровать", "опять цены вырастут", "он опять будет принимать наркотики", "я опять к тебе приду", "я опять подчеркну" etc.

Comment: @Netch I live in Moscow, you live in Kiev, possibly you tell me the Ukrainian norm instead of Russian one.

Comment: @Anixx Ваша позиция это чистое "если теория не сходится с фактами, то тем хуже для фактов":) теперь уже наперекор фактам утверждаете, что мне русский не родной. Не вижу смысла продолжать с такой позицией собеседника. И украинский тут ни при чём, в нём (литературном) аналога "опять" нет.

Comment: @Netch Факты заключаются в том, что "опять" в будущем времени применяется и очень интенсивно. Только несколько песен, которые используют фразу "я приду к тебе опять": http://www.stihi.ru/2012/11/04/295 http://fabulae.ru/poems_b.php?id=36474 http://world-of-love.ru/modules.php?name=Advicepoetry_his&page=14 http://webkind.ru/text/90281855_m54540354p946895803_text_pesni_sejlor-mun-5-sezon-httpvkontakteruclub20204620.html http://www.progressor.ru/stas/berg/part3.htm http://www.promegalit.ru/book.php?id=37 http://www.podvalchik.ru/index.php?showtopic=2463&view=all

Comment: @Anixx 1) в песнях может быть что угодно, лишь бы в размер влезло. 2) вернёмся к началу. Я писал (сейчас срезал, надо вернуть), что это базовые употребления, и границы между ними нежёсткие, так что это не запрещает и "опять" для намеренного действия, хотя и менее подходяще. Вы взвились дыбом и начали свой ответ с того, что я совсем неправ. Вам не кажется, что, мягко говоря, Ваша логика тут безнадёжно хромает? А теперь для защиты пытаетесь приписать мне украинский, приводить песни для примера и т.д. - лишь бы стоять насмерть.

Answer (score 4):

- *Ещё раз* means “one more time”.
- *Oпять* means “again”.
- *Снова* means “from the top, again, new beginning”.

Comment: Снова means "anew".

Answer (score 1):

Not from dictionaries, but from persional experience:

**Ещё раз** is mainly used when somebody asks to do something in a future, while **опять** and **снова** are preferred for finished actions.

> Ты должен позвонить ему ещё раз.

Then, *снова* is used for intentional actions, but *опять* for occasional (unexpected) ones, even in future. There is phrase which expresses that the action was intentional:

> Не «опять», а «снова»!

"Ещё раз" may be used for past events to put accent on repetition:

> Он ещё раз сходил за ёлкой, потом ещё раз... (["Падал прошлогодний снег"])

The boundaries between these meanings aren't strict and depend on speaker.

Comment: As for me it seems quite natural to use _опять_ for future actions, e. g. _Завтра я опять приду._

Comment: I see no problem in using "опять" for the future. "Надо его опять предупредить", "мне придется опять оставить его на работе". The idea that "опять" is used for non-intentional actions unlike the "снова" is also wrong. -1

Comment: @Anixx а мне крайне неуютно говорить "опять" для будущих, тем более спланированных, действий.